# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que en un menú pueda abrir un item de la lista?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un menú el cual lo voy a utilizar en dispositivo móvil y ya tengo la estructura del mismo, lo que me falta es darle un 100% de funcionalidad y actualmente puedo decir que lo tengo en un 70 a 75%.

Lo que me faltaría es poder abrir un submenú de un item que se encuentra en el primer orden o en el menú principal.

En la actualidad se ve de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver puedo hacer que se abra el submenú de los "COMPONENTES" y poder visualizar la lista.

En la parte de html en el item que va a tener un submenú en la clase le pongo la palabra 'subitem' y la línea de código con la que obtengo esa funcionalidad; a continuación parte de la estructura del html y la función:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$('.subitem').click(function(){
   $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

He intentado aplicar lo mismo con las sub sublistas pero no he podido lograr obtener esa funcionalidad, es decir, agregando la clase subitem en el

Quiero saber como puedo modificar el código para abrir los items "ALMACENAMIENTO" y "PERIFERICOS"
o que me recomiendan para obtener esa funcionalidad que hace falta en el menú.